# Elasticsearch painless, how to determine the data type of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

In es5.5, how to determine whether a field is numeric?

```
if (is_numeric(ctx._source.some)) {
    ctx._source.some = ctx._source.some + 2
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get the mapping and determine that? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html

Comment: i believe it can be done with painless. just don't get the way.

Comment: There is an instanceof that can be used to check against a reference type which you probably can use to define you own is_numeric function

Comment: "why don't you get the mapping" - maybe because the mapping varies across indices, and you want to find the type per document ... maybe to unearth some type conflicts? Well - that's what *I'd* like to do at the moment.

Comment: @sramalingam24 mapping is not necessary giving you the exact field type. By instance, a field can be an array or a concrete value, you cannot control that with mapping.

Answer (score 5):

The [instanceof](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/5.5/_operators.html#_instance_of) operator might help here

```
if (ctx._source.some instanceof byte ||
    ctx._source.some instanceof short ||
    ctx._source.some instanceof int ||
    ctx._source.some instanceof long ||
    ctx._source.some instanceof float ||
    ctx._source.some instanceof double)
{
    ctx._source.some = ctx._source.some + 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `Debug.explain`, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.8/painless-debugging.html

This will abort with a `painless_explain_error` and the output will tell you what classes are involved. With that information (obtained manually from your various indices across your various ElasticSearch versions), you can then implement Painless with `instanceof`, as shown in @oleg-grishko 's answer.

```
POST /hockey/player/1/_explain
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
       "script": "Debug.explain(doc.goals)"
    }
  }
}

{
   "error": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "painless_class": "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Longs",
       ...
```